# Download File from SFTP server without using JSch

Tags: java

Due to some policy constraint at our company, we cannot use any external Library. I couldn't find any way to do that in Java.

Comment: Write your own library. Sftp protocol specification is not a mistery. What's your problem? Describe your problem.

Comment: you would need to write similar code to what jsch does.

Comment: What a nonsense policy ...

Comment: Your company uses java and doesn't allow external Library? You need a new company, man

Comment: @LongNguyen Or the company needs better managers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways to avoid using an external library:

1. Implement your own SSH File Transfer Protocol client using the standard SSLSocket class ad related classes.  The specifications are linked from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol).   A brief review of the spec suggests that the protocol is not that complicated.
2. Identify and install a command-line client for SFTP, then use `Process` and `ProcessBuilder` to run the client as an external process.

---

Before you undertake any significant coding work on this, I would advise you to estimate how much dev time it will  take to code test and maintain the code.  If it seems like a lot, document the estimates and take them to your line manager.

- If you are faced with a significant amount of extra work, it may affect your ability to meet your deadlines.  Your manager needs to know about that.
- If your manager is faced with a large dev cost or schedule slippage, he or she may be prepared to argue for an exemption to this (IMO) crazy corporate policy.